# MySQL server PID file could not be found

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, pid, osx-mountain-lion

I can start MySQL fine,

```
/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
SUCCESS!
```

But any MySQL action after that I get the error:

> MySQL server PID file could not be found

```
/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
```

Where do I find the server PID file on Mac with OSX 10.8? I am wondering if it is a permission problem. The mysql.sock file is a symlink pointing to the file in the tmp/ directory.

```
sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: This can be caused by so many factors, i.e. permissions, ownership, corrupted data - to see a summary of how to determine which one, check this article: https://medium.com/@7anac/mysql-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file-ce320ff75828

Comment: I also experienced this issue on CentOS 6. After the investigation, I found out that it was just caused by the disk space that is 100% full. I freed up some disk space by removing old backup files and MySQL server was alive again!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your mysql configuration file - `my.cnf`, check for the parameter `pid-file` and see where it points. If it is not there, set it manually to -

```
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Create the directory `/var/run/mysqld/` and give it proper permissions -

```
  mkdir /var/run/mysqld
  touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
  chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

Comment: Okay, I am trying this. I will let you know how it goes

Comment: Great, you are a genius. It works. The only thing that was missing was the line pid-file in my.cnf

I had to run /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart twice to remove the error

Comment: I cannot find pid-file in my.cnf .. could I add this line `pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid` ??

Comment: yes, if you are getting "PID file not found" error.

Comment: @Danielt.thanks for your reply. I tried what you said.. the error is now changes to `ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid).` do u have any idea?! :|

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file

Comment: I did the above step and still getting error:
[15:57:53][~]#sudo mysql.server restart
 ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL
.. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid).

Answer (score 21):

This question is a bit outdated but I thought I'd post how I resolved this issue when it happened to me on my Mac (OS X El Capitan 10.11.4).

**Check the status just to be sure**

```
mysql.server status
```

> ERROR! MySQL is running but PID file could not be found

**Find all running mysql processes**

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

> It will list out all the processes using mysql (including the command you just executed)

**Kill off all the mysql pids**

```
sudo kill <pid1> <pid2> <pid3> ...
```

> This should kill off all the mysql processes

**Now try to fire mysql up**

```
mysql.server start
```

> Starting MySQL
>   . SUCCESS!

***Hope this helps someone!***

---

EDIT: Alternative solution from @DanielTate

> This worked for me [JasperSoft Wiki - uninstall-mysql-mac-os-x](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/uninstall-mysql-mac-os-x). I had to brew uninstall mysql then delete ALL of the files then reinstall and follow the home brew install instructions

---

EDIT 2: Alternative solution from @JanacMeena

> There is a nice write-up of their solution in this [post on Medium](https://medium.com/@7anac/mysql-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file-ce320ff75828).

Comment: ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file

Comment: @Nisanio Along with `ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file` does it give reference to a .pid file?  Maybe something similar to `ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/<userName>.<pidFileName>.pid)`

Comment: This worked for me http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/uninstall-mysql-mac-os-x. I had to brew uninstall mysql then delete ALL of the files then reinstall and follow the home brew install instructions

Comment: @DanielTate Thanks for adding that in w/the link. Should be helpful to others!

Comment: `ps aux | grep [m]ysql` will help prevent grep from grepping itself

Comment: @Nisanio did you figure out how to solve that issue?

Comment: @JanacMeena I've updated my answer to include Daniel Tate alt solution from comments, in the case Nisanio doesn't get back to you w/a solution.  Hopefully this helps unblock you, if not post back with more details; maybe I — or the community — can be of assistance

Comment: @Rockin4Life33 thanks for your response, but I was able to solve this issue by deleting my ibdata files and ib-log files.

Comment: For reference, I documented my solution here: https://medium.com/@7anac/mysql-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file-ce320ff75828

Comment: @JanacMeena, thank you for the write-up on Medium and posting the link.  I've updated the answer to contain your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Underlying issue is probably that your hostname is changing and if you do not specify the pid-file in my.cnf it will use .pid as the file. 
If I have my MacBook at home I will see one hostname but when it wakes up on the corporate network it will see the same name with ".local" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too... In my case,I used **Generic MySql** version, I run mysql as `root` user :

```
/path/to/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start --user=root
```